# Presto/Mysql join validation

Tags: mysql, amazon-presto

I have 2 tables, and the CASE statement below should only evaluate to 1/true if the record with the same lead_id exists in both tables. Here I have 2 ways of achieving this but just want to verify if its in fact the most optimal way of achieving this and which one is the better option here? The lead_id in t1 is the primary key and will always exist. I need to verify if its moved into the 2nd table

**Query 1**

```
SELECT
   CASE
      WHEN
         t1.lead_id = t2.lead_id 
      THEN
         1 
      ELSE
         0 
   END
   AS valid 
FROM
   table1 t1 
   LEFT JOIN
      table2 t2 
      ON t1.lead_id = t2.lead_id
```

**Query 2**

```
SELECT
   CASE
      WHEN
         t2.lead_id IS NOT NULL 
         AND t2.lead_id != 0 
      THEN
         1 
      ELSE
         0 
   END
   AS valid 
FROM
   table1 t1 
   LEFT JOIN
      table2 t2 
      ON t1.lead_id = t2.lead_id
```

Comment: Thanks @ErgestBasha for the suggestion but I need a 0 or 1 generated instead and not the actual lead_id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
SELECT t2.lead_id IS NOT NULL AS '1'
FROM table1 AS t1 
LEFT JOIN table2 AS t2 ON t1.lead_id = t2.lead_id ;
```

Tested on my server:

```
SELECT vs.status  IS NOT NULL AS '1'
FROM vicidial_log vl
LEFT JOIN vicidial_statuses vs ON vl.status = vs.status
WHERE campaign_id = 'my_campaign'
```

Result:

```
1
1
1
1
0
1
1
0
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
0
1
1
1
1
1
0
0
```

Answer (score 1):

even shorter...

```
SELECT t2.lead_id IS NOT NULL
    FROM table1 AS t1 
    LEFT JOIN table2 AS t2 ON t1.lead_id = t2.lead_id ;
```

A boolean expression evaluates as 0 (false) or 1 (true).

If really want the ids that match instead of 0/1, even simpler:

```
SELECT t1.lead_id
    FROM table1 AS t1 
    JOIN table2 AS t2 ON t1.lead_id = t2.lead_id ;
```

In all cases, `table2` needs an index starting with `lead_id`.  (Remember that the `PRIMARY KEY` is an index.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to have an extra field where you see if the entries from t1 are in t2, that is the easiest way. Personally I would have done it with an if statement like so:

```
SELECT
  t1.id,
  IF(t2.id IS NULL,0,1) 
FROM t1 
  LEFT JOIN t2 
  ON t1.id=t2.id;
```

If you just want to make sure a specific value is in a certain table, you can use the EXISTS() function like so:

```
SELECT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM t2 WHERE id=<value>);
```